# Using expect to migrate multiple repositories

Tags: expect, svn2git

I have multiple repositories , which I want to convert to git from svn.
I try to write a simple expect script that convert one repo.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect 

spawn svn2git svn://svn-server/repo --username $username --verbose 
expect {Password for '$username'} 
send "$password\r"
```

He puts password but then exit by timeout.

Answer (score 0):

Git launches SSH internally to connect to a remote repository, and SSH detects when it is launched from another program, and disallows to enter passwords from scripts as a security feature.

You will need a specialized program like `sshpass` to enter passwords into SSH from scripts, or set up SSH keys.

Comment: `expect` is such a specialized program. ssh thinks it is interacting with a user.

Answer (score 0):

I presume svn2git takes more than a few seconds to complete. Add this after your `send` command

```
set timeout -1
expect eof
```